# Laravel Eloquent: Is it possible to use "create" method for inserting multiple records as array?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

As Laravel document says we can insert "a" record using create eloquent method

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Is it possible to insert multiple records using create method without loop. i.e.

```
$flight = App\Flight::create([['name' => 'Flight 10'], ['name' => 'Flight 11']]);
```

Currently I am using insert method but it does not take care of created_at and updated_at values which I have to make fillable.

```
$flight = App\Flight::insert([['name' => 'Flight 10'], ['name' => 'Flight 11']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`create()` supports insert **only one record**.

`insert()` supports insert **many records**.

`createMany()` just support **only for relationship**, not Model.

So you only can choose `insert()` method for this eloquent builder.

However, you can use `useCurrent()` in your migration, so the default value will **automatically** set the **current time**.

```php
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
```

This will work to `insert()` method without manually set the timestamp:

```php
$flight = App\Flight::insert([['name' => 'Flight 10'], ['name' => 'Flight 11']);
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

insert does not add the timestamp values so you have to put manually

```
 $data = [
    [
      'name' => 'Flight 10'
       'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'Flight 11'
       'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]
 ];

App\Flight::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually fill timestamps.

```
$data_to_create = [
[
  'name' => 'Flight 10'
   'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
],
[
  'name' => 'Flight 11'
   'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]
];

App\Flight::insert($data_to_create);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$data = [
[
  'name' => 'Flight 10'
   'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
],
[
  'name' => 'Flight 11'
   'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H`enter code here`:i:s')
]
```

];

App\Flight::createMany($data);